# Array within Structure for printing basic informations of person

Tags: c

I have tried this code for printing some persons' basic information. Here is the code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct person {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float salary;
};

int main() {
    struct person p[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Enter informations for person no %d:\n\n",i+1);
        printf("Enter name : \n");
        gets(p[i].name);
        printf("Enter age : \n");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].age);
        printf("Enter salary : \n");
        scanf("%f",&p[i].salary);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n\nInformations for person no %d:\n\n",i+1);
        printf("Name: %s\n",p[i].name);
        printf("Age : %d\n",p[i].age);
        printf("Salary : %0.2f\n",p[i].salary);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now while scanning data, this code takes only takes all the information of first person and doesn't take character type data of others.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend using `fgets()` instead of `gets()` because gets can be dangerous (In order to use `gets()` safely, you have to know exactly how many characters you will be reading, so that you can make your buffer large enough).
   `fgets()` also takes the '\n' char at the end, in order to prevent this you can write the following line: `p[i].name[strlen(p[i].name)-1] = '\0';`
2. Your main problem is that salary input leaves '\n' character, and you need to collect it with getchar();

So you need to write something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    float salary;
};

int main() {
    struct person p[3];
    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Enter informations for person no %d:\n\n",i+1);
        printf("Enter name : \n");
        fgets(p[i].name,100,stdin);
        p[i].name[strlen(p[i].name)-1] = '\0';
        printf("Enter age : \n");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].age); 
        printf("Enter salary : \n");
        scanf("%f",&p[i].salary); 
        getchar();
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n\nInformations for person no %d:\n\n",i+1);
        printf("Name: %s\n",p[i].name);
        printf("Age : %d\n",p[i].age);
        printf("Salary : %0.2f\n",p[i].salary);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try out: `Enter salary: <num> <space> <enter>`.

Comment: Yes, it will pick up the space char and leave '\n', but I don't think that's the point of this problem.